# webpack converts some images to urls and appends characters to others

Tags: css, image, sass, base64, webpack

I'm trying to apply a tiled background image with a tinted overlay to my project. I'm using webpack with node-sass, the sass-loader, css-loader, file-loader, and url-loader amongst my other node packages.

I have two background images that I was testing the look of, and switching between these two images as the background is where I ran into my issue.

Here's the sass:

```
body{
    background:
        linear-gradient(
            rgba($color4, .5),
            rgba($color4, .5)
        ),
        url('../assets/dark_fish_skin.png')
        // url('../assets/noisy_grid.png')
    ;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    color: $color2;
}
```

And here's a look at the sass file, file directory, and the two images in my src file just to give overall context (compiled output is sent to the `public` folder):

[image: overall file structure]

When I run webpack with the `dark_fish_skin.png` as the background image, the image comes through fine because it's converted to a base64 encoded url:

[image: with darkfish png]

When I switch over to the `noisy_grid.png` image and run webpack, the image comes through as a regular image but with a cache buster(assuming) appended to the end, the file is moved into the public directory but without the cache buster in the name, and I get an error because the css reference doesn't match the image name:

[image: error in browser]

[image: public directory after webpack run]
(please excuse the messy public directory, this is still a wip).

I've been looking around in the docs but I haven't been able to find a solution for this issue.

Two questions: why is this happening (link to the explanation in the docs would be great) and how would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

node-sass doesn't convert url connects unless you apply some sort of iterpolation. See http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/d6051eeb2f3bade7eb6d453158e3faf6
This is likely something in webpack doing it